# I am getting different file write speeds for similar programs. How?

Tags: java, variables, random

I wrote a simple program as shown, which simply generates a random character, and prints that character to a file. This keeps on going infinitely until the program is terminated.

I made these 3 similar programs, with minor code difference, but huge practical difference.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class RandomCharInfinity
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        PrintStream save = new PrintStream(new File("virus.txt"));
        Random r = new Random();

        while(true) 
        {
            save.print((char)(r.nextInt(26)+'a'));
        }
    }
}
```

This code generated file virus.txt, with 45 mb size in just 30 seconds.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class RandomCharInfinity
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        PrintStream save = new PrintStream(new File("virus.txt"));
        Random r = new Random();
        while(true) 
        {
            save.print((char)(r.nextInt(26)+'a'));
            save.print((char)(r.nextInt(26)+'a'));
            save.print((char)(r.nextInt(26)+'a'));
            save.print((char)(r.nextInt(26)+'a'));
            save.print((char)(r.nextInt(26)+'a'));
            save.print((char)(r.nextInt(26)+'a'));
            save.print((char)(r.nextInt(26)+'a'));
            save.print((char)(r.nextInt(26)+'a'));
            save.print((char)(r.nextInt(26)+'a'));
            save.print((char)(r.nextInt(26)+'a'));
        }
    }
}
```

This code generated file virus.txt with size approx 15 mb in 30 seconds.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class RandomCharInfinity
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        PrintStream save = new PrintStream(new File("virus.txt"));
        Random r = new Random();
        char ch = (char)(r.nextInt(26)+'a')
        while(true) 
        {
            save.print(ch);
        }
    }
}
```

This also generated virus.txt with 15 mb in 30 seconds.

Now my question is, in the last program, i am taking a single random character and just printing it infinite times.

In middle program, I am printing 10 random characters at a time with single while loop verification.

In first program, I am printing a random character, and each time I have to verify the while loop.

Why is it that these programs are diffenrnt sizes and that too by a huge difference?

Comment: How did you measure throughput?

Comment: All three programs should have pretty identical performance. How do you measure?

Comment: I'm going to go with "random OS caching differences".

Comment: Looking at the code, I would say by hitting CTRL-C at the 30s mark.

Comment: I simply run the compiled program via command prompt in windows. As soon as i press enter, writing to the file begins. I start a stopwatch  as i press enter, and wait for 30 seconds after which i close the command prompt.

I did this for all three programs. i even increased the time but still, got the same disk space ratio.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely on file sizes if you do not close the file properly from within your program, so your conclusions have been made on invalid data.

Rewrite your programs to generate a specific amount of output, and measure how long it took with System.currentTimeMillis().

(Also note that IO is usually *much* slower than CPU work, so the best way to speed output up is to buffer the OutputStreams - which PrintStream may already be doing)

Comment: Count the bytes you write and stop at e.g. 640 million.  Ask the JVM for the current time in milliseconds when you start, and when you stop, and subtract the two numbers to get an approximate value of the number of miliseconds it took you to write those bytes.  Write that to standard out.